# Плавный CloseWindow() winapi

Tags: c++, winapi

В windows 11 при сворачивании приложения, они сворачиваются с анимацией(все приложения), как в macos (анимация сворачивание приложения в точку ярлыка на панели задач). Я пытался использовать
**CloseWindow(hWnd);** и **ShowWindow(hWNd, );** Но приложения сворачиваются резко - не плавно. Подскажите, как реализовать плавность

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/658067/

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать постепенное уменьшение размера окна с помощью `SetWindowPos(...)` и в самом конце просто использовать функцию `ShowWindow(...)`